# Array, Finding if value is diagonally of your chosen x,y

Tags: c++, arrays, c++builder, tstringgrid

So, i have a problem

i found out that:
if my position is [7][3] and the object is on [2][8]
the sum of the x,y is the same for both of them. ex: 7+3 = 2+8
but i'm stuck on finding the same thing on the other side

if you don't understand what i mean i can try to explain again

Comment: Can you explain? Also what is your error and do you have code?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with C++ or even arrays - it's to do with geometry.  If you are at (x,y) and the object is at x-1,y+1, then indeed the sum of the coordinates is unchanged.  Are you also interested in an object at (x-20,y+20)?  If so,consider the difference between the coordinates.

Comment: i know this, i'm trying to find the way of finding (x-1,y-1)(x-2,y-2) and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhat unclear what exactly you are looking for, but maybe this helps:

All 2D coordinates `a`,`b` which are diagonally offset from `x`,`y` meet the condition

```
abs(a-x) == abs(b-y)
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for, thanks now i can finish my Graduation project :)